# How to overload operators with a built-in return type?

Tags: c++

Say I have a class, that wraps some mathematic operation. Lets use a toy example

```
class Test
{
public:
   Test( float f ) : mFloat( f ), mIsInt( false ) {}

   float mFloat;
   int   mInt;
   bool  mIsFloat;
};
```

I'd like to create an operator overload with the following prototype:

```
float operator=( const Test& test ) 
{ 
    if ( !test.mIsFloat ) return *this; // in this case don't actually do the assignment
    return test.mFloat;                      // in this case do it.
}
```

So my questions are: can I overload operator= with a built-in return type?
and if so, is there a way to refer to the built-in type?

I know I could do this if I wrapped the built-ins with a class. But in this case I want to have the assignment operator work with built-in types on the LHS

Example of usage:

```
Test t( 0.5f );
float f = t; // f == 0.5
int   i = 0;
i = t;       // i stays 0.
```

UPDATE: Thanks so much for the help. Expanding a little bit from the toy example so people understand what I'm really trying to do.

I have a configuration system that allows me to get config parameters from a tree of parameters with different type ( they can be integers, floats, strings, arrays etc. ).

I can get items from the tree with operations like this:

```
float updateTime = config["system.updateTime"];
```

But it is possible that "system.updateTime" does not exist. Or is of the wrong type. Generally for configuration I have a block of defaults, and then code to overide the defaults from the config:

```
float updateTime = 10;
const char* logFile = "tmp.log";
... etc etc...
```

I want to do something like:

```
updateTime = config["system.updateTime"];
```

Where the operation succeeds if there is an override. So generally the assignment doesn't happen if the return from operator[] is an "invalid" node in the tree.

Right now I solve it with a function like:

```
getConfig( config, "system.updateTime", updateTime );
```

But I would prefer to use assignment operator.

I could do this if I were willing to create classes to wrap the builtins.

```
class MyFloat
{
   operator=( const Test& test ) { if (test.isValidNode() ) f = test.float(); return *this; }
   float f;
}
```

But obviously it would be prefereable not to wrap built-ins with trivial classes just to overload assignment. Question is - is this possible in c++?

Comment: *"But in this case I want to have the assignment operator work with built-in types on the LHS"* -- Please explain what you mean by this, and give examples.  It's not immediately clear what your goal is.

Comment: Did you try it? Just put the code in the `operator=` snippet into the class definition.

Comment: Wrong operator your trying to use. Use the `cast operator`.

Comment: Cast operator would not allow me to set the float or integer conditionally.

Comment: If you want some form of type safety you should consider a template specialization solution.

Comment: @ahenderson: how would that work?

Comment: @RafaelBaptista Using a method like `try_assign()` as per my example is probably the right solution.  Using the assignment operator in this instance is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, what you really want is an implicit conversion operator:

```
class Test
{
    // ...
public:
    operator float() const;
};

inline Test::operator float() const
{
    return mIsFloat ? mFloat : mInt;
}
```

If you want to conditionally do the assignment, then you need to take another approach.  A named method would probably be the best option, all things considered... something like this:

```
class Test
{
public:
    bool try_assign(float & f) const;
};

inline bool Test::try_assign(float & f) const
{
    if (mIsFloat) {
        f = mFloat;
    }

    return mIsFloat;
}
```

Whatever you do, be careful that the syntactic sugar you introduce doesn't result in unreadable code.

Comment: This is for a configuration class with a tree of values. Assignment to runtime parameters from configuration file would be conditional. E.g. int updateTime = 10; updateTime = config["updateTime"]; // set conditionally if config param exists.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista If it's conditional, then using the assignment operator would be inappropriate anyway.  It will confuse developers who (rightly) expect assignment to always happen.

Comment: I guess what I want can't be done. And maybe its a bad idea anyway. I'll stick with my current method of conditional getting using a function. Essentially your "try_assign" which I was already doing.

Answer (score 1):

You already have one implicit conversion from `float` to `Test`, in the form of the convert constructor

```
class Test
{
public:
 /* ... */
Test( float f ) : mFloat( f ) /*...*/ {}       

};
```

Which will support conversions such as:

```
Test t(0.5f);
```

You will likely also want a copy-assignement operator in order to make further implicit conversions from `float` to `Test` possible:

```
class Test
{
public:

    Test& operator=(float f) { mFloat = f; return *this; }  
};

t = 0.75; // This is possible now
```

In order to support implicit conversion from `Test` to `float` you don't use `operator=`, but a custom cast operator, declared & implemented thusly:

```
class Test
{
public:
  /* ... */
  operator float () const { return mFloat; }
};
```

This makes implicit conversions posslible, such as:

```
float f = t;
```

As an aside, you have another implicit conversion happening here you may not even be aware of.  In this code:

```
Test t( 0.5 );
```

The literal value `0.5` isn't a `float`, but a `double`.  In order to call the convert constructor this value must be converted to `float`, which may result in loss of precision.  In order to specify a `float` literal, use the `f` suffix:

```
Test t( 0.5f );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using template specialization:**

```
class Config {
    template<typename T>
    void setValue(const std::string& index, T& value); //sets the value if available
};

template<float>
void Config::setValue(const std::string& index, float& value){...} //only sets float values

template<int>
void Config::setValue(const std::string& index, int& value){...} //only sets int values;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "overload/add" operators for basic types, but you can for your type `Type`. But this shall not be `operator =` but `operator >>` - like in `istream`s.

```
class Test
{
public:
   float mFloat;
   int   mInt;
   bool  mIsFloat;
   Test& operator >> (float& v) { if (mIsFloat) v = mFloat; return *this; }
   Test& operator >> (int& v) { if (!mIsFloat) v = mInt; return *this; }
};
```

Then you can:

```
int main() {
  float v = 2;
  Test t = { 1.0, 2, false };
  t >> v; // no effect
  t.mIsFloat = true;
  t >> v; // now v is changed
}
```

**Update**

> I want to do something like:

```
updateTime = config["system.updateTime"];
```

Then with my proposal, you cam:

```
config["system.updateTime"] >> updateTime;
```

Comment: This is not the accepted use for the stream operators and is likely to be confusing to users of the class.

Comment: @Dan actually this is shift operator, reused by C++ streams years ago. My choice is as good/bad as theirs. I believe such usage will not be a surprise for C++ folks.

Comment: -1: `operator>>` will not provide for *implicit* conversions, which is apparently what OP really wants based on the fact that they are trying to implement `float Test::operator=()`.

Comment: @JohnDibling it doesn't really look like implicit conversions are what the question calls for to me. The question seems to be looking for a way to write `float myConfigValue = config["param"];` and somehow have the assignment _not_ occur based on conditions of the config object and the type of the object being assigned to.